# How to play notification sound from scheduled agent?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

my app has a scheduled agent that checks for new mails and updates the tile if new mails received, i'd also like to play a notification sound from the background agent to notify the user about new mails like the google mail app does, however I haven't found anything except to the SoundEffect which seems not usable from scheduled task.
is there a way to play such notification sound?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to play a sound from a background agent. (see the list of [Unsupported APIs for Background Agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202962%28v=vs.92%29.aspx))

If you want to notify the user of a change you could raise a `ShellToast` instead. (depending on the users settings this may play a sound.)